# Lag with dual external monitors when primary display disabled on 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, displaylink

The setup ran fine (18.04) before my upgrade to 22.04.

It is a Lenovo Thinkpad with a DisplayLink USB-C dock with two external monitors connected.

Nvidia info: TU117GLM [Quadro T2000 Mobile / Max-Q]

With all three displays enabled, the performance is normal, but disabling the primary display leads to severe performance drop / screen lag. The primary needs to be disabled or windows sometimes spawn there, and there is no desk space for all three.

Things already attempted:

- different versions of nvidia drivers (currently using 470, as it worked in 18.04, and 525/525-open weren't working well)
- enabling/disabling wayland
- gdm3/lightdm
- reducing external resolution
- synaptic displaylink drivers

Answer (score 0):

It isn't perfect, but 515 (non-open) with reduced resolution provides adequate performance.